# Can't QOverload private signal, using Qt docs example

Tags: c++, qt

[Here in the Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html#activated) is written:

> Note: This is a private signal. It can be used in signal connections
> but cannot be emitted by the user.
>
> Note: Signal activated is overloaded in this class. To connect to this
> signal by using the function pointer syntax, Qt provides a convenient
> helper for obtaining the function pointer as shown in this example:

```
connect(socketNotifier, QOverload<QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type>::of(&QSocketNotifier::activated),
    [=](QSocketDescriptor socket, QSocketNotifier::Type type){ /* ... */ });
```

When I use it, I'm getting this issue:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'of'

/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1224: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 (QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type) const' against 'void (QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal)'

/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1212: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction

/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1241: candidate template ignored: could not match 'R (*)(QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type)' against 'void (QSocketNotifier::*)(QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal)'
```

I just copy-pasted the example and have `<QSocketDescriptor>` and `<QSocketNotifier>` headers both included. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but you are using Qt 5.15 correct?

Comment: No need for QOverload here at all since there is only one QSignalNotifier::activated() function so no ambiguity and no need for QOverload.

Comment: @mascoj 5.15 because Qt6 doesn't have QSerialPort and I need it

Comment: @chehrlic it's overloaded, it's also activated(int) there :( 5.15, sorry I didn't mention the version. It in the code comment that it will be deleted so it's probably gone in Qt6 but the question stands, why can't I QOverload like that?

Comment: also, I solved it by using old connect syntax with SIGNAL/SLOT macros, I'm still curious how to do it properly and why doesn't it work.

Comment: Ah, it's because of `activated(QSocketDescriptor socket, QSocketNotifier::Type activationEvent, QPrivateSignal)` - the QPrivateSignal is the culprit. No idea how to work around this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use C++14 you can use a helper function:

```cpp
template<class T> auto privateOverload(void ( QSocketNotifier::* s)( QSocketDescriptor,QSocketNotifier::Type,T ) ){return s;}
```

and then you can use

```cpp
QObject::connect(socketNotifier, privateOverload(&QSocketNotifier::activated),/*...*/);
```

If you can use C++20 you can also use a lambda directly in the connect statement:

```cpp
QObject::connect(socketNotifier, []<class T>(void ( QSocketNotifier::* s)( QSocketDescriptor,QSocketNotifier::Type,T ) ){return s;}(&QSocketNotifier::activated),/*...*/);
```